# Using lodash to filter the elements of an array with another

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Lets say I have the two following arrays

```
[{
    name: "one"
 },
 {
   name: "two" //need an array containing this
 }
];

[{
    name: "one"
}];
```

How would I filter the first array to contain only the elements NOT listed in the second using lodash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var second = [{name: "one"}, {name: "two"}];
var first  = [{name: "one"}];

first  = _.pluck(first, 'name'); // get all names - ['one']
second = _.filter(second, function (el) {
  return _.indexOf(first, el.name) === -1;  // search every name in first array  
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/rovaru/1/edit?js,console)